# how to use the new extension functions in okhttp 4

Tags: kotlin, okhttp, kotlin-extension

Hi got this compile error when upgrading from okHttp version 3 to version 4:

```
val JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8")
//Compile Error: Kotlin: Using 'parse(String): MediaType?' is an error. moved to extension function
```

I changed the call to invoke the extension method as the error points but the method is not recognizes as an String extension.

Here is how i did changed it:

```
val JSON = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaType()
```

Adding the import for Companion Objects as posted in [tutorial](https://square.github.io/okhttp/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/) also didn't solve it:

```
import okhttp3.CipherSuite.Companion.forJavaName
```

What did i miss here?

Comment: The addition of these extension functions is just hideous. Why every String should be considered a potential URL and every ByteArray a potential HTTP Response?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
```

Comment: is there auto import? Do I have to fill it out all the time?

Comment: Thats the problem. CTRL + Enter wont do it for you.

Comment: it's due to a bug in Kotlin IntelliJ plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15286 supposed to be fixed in 1.3.70

Comment: Crazy that this isn't found in the okhttp docs, I was really scratching my head on their recipe page. Thank you.